# Libsvm module in Rapidminer

Tags: svm, libsvm, rapidminer

Rapidminer has a SVM module based on libsvm. How can I know which version of libsvm it uses?

I tested the SVM classifier against the same data set using both libsvm module in Rapidminer and Libsvm itself, and the resulting prediction score are different even they use the same parameter setting.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the RapidMiner's root directory in the file CHANGES.txt (e.g. RM_HOME/CHANGES.txt):

...

- Completely revised tree, cluster model, and similarity
  visualization
- **Latest release of LibSVM integrated (2.84)**
- Latest release of xstream integrated (1.2.2)

...